# Service not run on app closed

Tags: java, android

The service works normally when is started from the MainActivity however when the application is removed from the recent apps or when activity is closed, the service is restarted instead of continuing from where it left off.

```
public class ServiceExample extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate();
    //Do Something
}
```

I need to perform an action in the background but it can not be stopped or restarted when the activity ends. The Service Statement is the best to Use?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this inside your service class.

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: This also make service to restart.

Comment: START_NOT_STICK; Service close

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to service and override `onStartCommand` and `return START_STICKY`

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());    
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartPendingIntent
    );

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Comment: This make service relaunched